# CSS color is ignored

Tags: css

I have a CSS class

```
.footer {
  background-image: url("images/background.png");
  position: fixed;
  width: 85%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #2e2929;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

All is fine but text color is ignored. I also tried to add a class but without effect.

```
a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: If you can include the full code or the URL to a demo then we can look into the overriding code.

Comment: #2e2929 doesn't look anything like a red color. Are you sure you are using the right color code?

Comment: #2e2929 Yes this is Right Color Code

Answer (score 0):

Try this !!

```css
.footer {
  background-image: url("images/background.png");
  position: fixed;
  width: 85%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: red;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class='footer'>AAAaaaBBBbbbCCCccc</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The color you are using (#2e2929) does not exist

Answer (score 0):

> Try this it will be worked fine..

```css
.footer {
  background-image: url("images/background.png");
  position: fixed;
  width: 85%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #2e2929;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.footer a{ color:red;}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
<a href="#">Anchor Link</a>
<div>
```